# Delete message with specific words on telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I wrote a bot to delete some words from a telegram group.

```
function filter_messages() {
    global $telegram;

    $bad_words = [
        'hello',
        'hi'
    ];

    $all_words = end( explode( ' ', $telegram->Text() ) );

    if ( in_array( $all_words, $bad_words ) ) {
        deletMessage();
    }

}
```

it works when a user sends a message like "hello". Robot deletes the message.
but when he sends "hello guys"
the robot does not delete the messeage.

Answer (score 0):

I used strpos() function.

```
if(strpos($all_words,$bad_words)!==false){
    deletMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_messages() {
    global $telegram;

    $bad_words = [
        'hello',
        'hi'
    ];

    //Make the array $badword to a (commaseparated) string
    $badwords_to_string = implode(",", $bad_words);

    //And then check if the any of the bad words in the telegramText exists
    //based on that $telegram->Text() is a string
    if (strpos($badwords_to_string, $telegram->Text()) !== false) {
        deletMessage();
    }

}
```